# How to use a custom functional interface with a method taking 2 arguments in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, functional-interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Test{

     int sum(int a, int b);

}
```

How can we use this sum method to add all elements of an ArrayList?
Note: Want to use stream as well.

Some users have suggested that sum method is already available for this purpose; my aim was not to sum the elements of a list, **it was to understand how would we use a custom functional interface on a list.**

Comment: First of all, the method should have an `int` return value. Otherwise it can't be used to compute a sum.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the method or do you have to use it?

Comment: Why do you need it over using existing stream methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your functional interface's sum method return an integer, you could use the reduce method from stream. So your functional interface would be:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Test{

    int sum(int a, int b);

}
```

And here is the example of reduce method:

```
yourArraysList.stream().reduce(0, testImpl::sum);
```

Where testImpl is an instance of the implementation of the functional interface Test.

There's also a sum() method on stream, that deals with sum of stream's elements.

Reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

Comment: Thanks Felipe, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your functional interface is as follows :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Test {
    int sum(int a, int b);
}
```

You can use lambda function for the implementation of the functional interface (sum method), and use reduce method from the stream (ideally sum method is not needed if you want to use stream since the lambda function can be used directly within the reduce method) :

```
Test test = (a, b) -> a+b;
someArrayList.stream().reduce(0, test::sum);
```

Comment: Thanks Staphy, this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Before you implement anything against your `interface Test` mind if and how you want to process the result of the method. In this case, there wouldn't be any result returned because you have declared the method as `void`.

You could start with a method that actually returns a result and takes the desired argument:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Test {

    /**
     * <p>
     * Sums up all the values provided in the given list.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param list the list of numbers to be summed up
     * @return the sum of all the values
     */
    default int sum(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue))
    }
}
```

Then implement the method in some class that `implements Test` or use the `default` implementation.

> Note that **the result of summing several `int`s or `Integer`s may become greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`**
>   and
>   **this `interface` won't compile as long as there is no method without `default` implementation**.